# WSO2 BAM - Data Purge option in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

Is there any way to remove raw events which are accumulated for long time in cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment WSO2 BAM does not support. But this functionality is supported in the next release, BAM 2.1.0 which will be released in very near future.